# crash on coredata delete in concurrency scenario: CoreData could not fulfill a fault

Tags: ios, core-data

We are running into many concurrency related crashes related to core data and deletes with our app, so I created a small project to reproduce one of those scenario.
I am able to reproduce a crash with "CoreData could not fulfill a fault" in the following scenario:
- I have 2 child contexts A, B, both associated with the same main parent content.
- the coredata model is very simple, one ConferenceRoom object has many Line objects.
- context A and B have concurrency type "NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType", parent with type "NSMainQueueConcurrencyType"
- thread 1 fetches an object from child context A, faults it, deletes it in context A and the main parent context
- thread 2 fetches the same object from child context B, waits for 2 seconds, saves it in the context B and the main parent context.

-->the app crashes in thread2 with "CoreData could not fulfill a fault" when it tries to save to child context B

Note that we've already fixed issues after trying the new xcode6 coredata debug flag:"-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 ", so no threading warning/issues in theory...
So can anyone explain how we can avoid those crashes? (I can send the full project if needed).

Here is the code (I am a novice ios developer, and it's quick/dirty code for sure)

Core methods:

```
//this creates a Conference and a Line object (called from AppDelegate when app launches
- (void) testCrash
{


NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *initConfName = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

//fix
[self.managedObjectChildContext performBlockAndWait:^{

    ConferenceRoom *room = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ConferenceRoom" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectChildContext];

    room.name = initConfName;

    Line *line1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Line" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectChildContext];
    line1.phoneNumber = @"4154243243";

    NSMutableSet *lines = [room mutableSetValueForKey:@"lines"];
    [lines addObject:line1];
}];



[self saveChildContext];
[self saveContext];


NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(mainThread1:)
                                           object:initConfName];
[myThread start];


NSThread* myThread2 = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                              selector:@selector(mainThread2:)
                                               object:initConfName];
[myThread2 start];

}



- (void) mainThread1:(NSString *) initConfName
{
NSLog(@"started thread 1");

//GET OBJ FROM CHILD CONTEXT 1



[self.managedObjectChildContext performBlockAndWait:^{

    NSArray *results = [self getConfRoom: self.managedObjectChildContext withName:initConfName];
    NSLog(@"C1 conf:%@", results);

    ConferenceRoom *roomFoundChild1 = [results lastObject];

    NSArray *linesc1 = [[roomFoundChild1 mutableSetValueForKey:@"lines"] allObjects];
    Line *linec1 = [linesc1 firstObject];
    NSLog(@"LINEC1=%@", linec1);

    //DELETE CONF IN CHILD CONTEXT 1:


    NSLog(@"Thread1:going to delete conference %@", roomFoundChild1);
    [self.managedObjectChildContext deleteObject: roomFoundChild1];
}];


NSLog(@"Thread1: before saving child context");
[self saveThisContext: self.managedObjectChildContext];
NSLog(@"Thread1: before saving main context");
//test: save in main context, works without this
[self saveContext];



}

- (void) mainThread2:(NSString*) initConfName
{
NSLog(@"started thread 2");

//GET OBJ FROM CHILD CONTEXT 2

__block NSArray *results;
__block ConferenceRoom *roomFoundChild2;
__block NSString *newName;

[self.managedObjectChildTwoContext performBlockAndWait:^{
     results = [self getConfRoom: self.managedObjectChildTwoContext withName:initConfName];
     NSLog(@"C2 conf\n:%@", results);

     roomFoundChild2 = [results lastObject];
     NSString *n = roomFoundChild2.name;

     //UPDATE CONF ROOM IN CHILD CONTEXT 2

     newName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", initConfName, @"newName2"];

     NSLog(@"Thread 2 waiting");
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
     NSLog(@"Thread 2 resuming");

     roomFoundChild2.name = newName;

     NSLog(@"roomFoundChild2, %@", roomFoundChild2);

 }];


NSLog(@"Thread2: before saving child context");
[self saveThisContext:self.managedObjectChildTwoContext];

NSLog(@"Thread2: after saving to child context");
results = [self getConfRoom:self.managedObjectChildTwoContext withName:newName];

NSLog(@"C2 context after delete:%@", results);


NSLog(@"Thread2: before saving main context");
//test: save in main context, works without this
[self saveContext];



}




- (void)saveContext
{
// NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {

    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{

        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved ERROR %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();

            };
        }
    }];

}

}




- (void)saveChildContext
{
// NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectChildContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {

    //COREDATAFLAG CHANGE


    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved ERROR %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();

            };
        }
    }];


}
}



- (void) saveThisContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *)ctx
{
if (ctx != nil) {

    [ctx performBlockAndWait:^{

        if ([ctx hasChanges]) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![ctx save:&error]) {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved ERROR %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                    //removed abort to test..
                    //abort();

            };
        }
    }];

}


}
```

Comment: currently trying to replicate your error, and it'll help to have code for how you created the two child contexts and your getConfRoom: method although I'm just creating them in the basic way i think they should be done.

Comment: i wasn't able to reproduce the crash. If you're still looking for an answer, maybe you can create a git repo for your project.

Answer (score 0):

`//test: save in main context, works without this
[self saveContext];`

You can't call that method from thread 2 because it is saving your main thread context, which can only be saved/edited/etc from the main thread.  There are several ways of handling this, but one thing you can do is `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(saveContext)];`